# Determine the struct member through function parameter

Tags: c++, struct

I want to create a function which will assign the value of the struct array and it will determine the member of struct through its parameter.

I mean instead of creating seperate function for each member of the struct, determine the member through the function parameter(examples : &.tests, lessons.exams)

The Code ı wrote down is only for explain what I mean, values can be imported from a text file instead of assigning them by random.

What I want to understand is; is there any other way to call struct member without writing its name?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct lsn
{
    char name[20];
    int tests[4];
    int quizzes[4];
    int exams[4];
    int finals[4];
};

void random_notes(lsn *x, int *y)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++);
            x[i].y[j]=rand()%101;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    lsn lessons[30];
    random_notes(lessons, &.tests);
    random_notes(lessons, &.quizzes);
    random_notes(lessons, &.exams);
    random_notes(lessons, &.finals);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of creating 4 functions as below,

```
void random_tests(lsn *x)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            for(j=0;j<4;j++);
                x[i].tests[j]=rand()%101;
    }

void random_quizzes(lsn *x)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            for(j=0;j<4;j++);
                x[i].quizzes[j]=rand()%101;
    }

void random_exams(lsn *x)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            for(j=0;j<4;j++);
                x[i].exams[j]=rand()%101;
    }

void random_finals(lsn *x)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            for(j=0;j<4;j++);
                x[i].finals[j]=rand()%101;
    }
```

Just one function that determine the struct member throuh its parameter,

```
void random_notes(lsn *x, .struct_member y)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            for(j=0;j<4;j++);
                x[i].y[j]=rand()%101;
    }
```

In this example the function is very small, but imagine a huge code in a fuction, only the struct member is different and rest of the code is same.

Comment: If you have another question, please [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) properly. Do not pile onto an already answered post and invalidate the answers given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, C++ has a concept of "pointers to members". This will allows you to pass the identity of the member you wish to initialize. The syntax is a bit wonky however, so beware:

```
void random_notes(lsn *x, int (lsn::* y)[4])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++);
            (x[i].*y)[j]=rand()%101; // << Access the member of x[i] via y
}
```

Which is to be called like this:

```
random_notes(lessons, &lsn::tests);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function which when called returns the appropriate struct member. For example:

```
random_notes(lessons, [=](lsn& lesson) { return lesson.quizzes; });
```

in `random_notes` function, you just call the function with a `lsn` instance and it will give you the array to populate